# The 'official' way to deploy multiple Rail 3.1 Apps with Passenger

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, apache2, passenger

I'm currently trying to get a couple of small Rails apps running on a server, normally I've used Heroku but I decided to DIY it this time for practise, and everything that is suggested on the Internet doesn't work.

I've tried pretty much all of the resources I can find on both SO and the full Phusion guide, the closest I can come is "The page you were looking for doesn't exist." The app itself runs fine when I run it with script/rails server, initalizing a new rails app to a different sub_dir runs fine, but it'll only let me use index.html, nothing else. So it looks like some kind of routing issue, but when I tried the "scope do" it falls over on "scope".

What's the actual recommended and suggested way to have multiple rails sites on sub uris?

**Apache2 Configuration File**

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
    <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.cybershrike.co.uk/
    DocumentRoot /web/rails
    <Directory /web/rails>
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    RailsBaseURI /test
    <Directory /web/rails/test>
        Options -MultiViews
    </Directory>
    </VirtualHost>

    NameVirtualHost *:80
    <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.cybershrike.co.uk/
    DocumentRoot /web/rails
    <Directory /web/rails>
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    RailsBaseURI /kinu
    RailsEnv development
    SetEnv RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT "/kinu"
    PassengerAppRoot /web/rails/kinu
    <Directory /web/rails/kinu/public>
        Options MultiViews Indexes FollowSymLinks
    </Directory>
    </VirtualHost>
```

Comment: could you support your question with a sample configuration you're using? 
p.s. you don't deploy with passenger, passenger is just the server/rack plugin that runs your app. for deployment you're usually using capistrano or vlad.

Comment: @robustus: just updating now with a sample Apache vhost, and apologies for mixed terminology, I'm actually deploying with git and symlinking to the Rails project folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the proposed default passenger option?

```
  RailsBaseURI /kinu
  RailsEnv development
  <Directory /web/rails/kinu/public>
    Options -MultiViews
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Also you have to ensure, that file-permission allow the apache-server (ususally wwwuser) to access all files recursively including /web ?
And, just to cover all bases here: did you restart apache?

Comment: Tried, it still just gives "page does not exist". I hadn't specifically set the apache2 user as the owner of the folder (www-data for me in this case apparently). Thanks for suggesting it though, totally forgot that part.

Comment: Actually this tip got me a little bit further, so it's now just a routing issue. However a plain test Rails site created locally on the server *does* work, so there's something in the config that seems to be killing it. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: This actually worked, however the way it's structured seems fairly fluid but I stripped it all back to that and it was fine.